# Webpack: include html files and their js scripts alongside standalone js scripts

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I current have a project that follows this structure:

```
src/
├── browserAction/
│   ├── assets/
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── script.js
│   └── style.css
├── options/
│   ├── assets/
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── script.js
│   └── style.css
├── manifest.json
├── background_script.js
└── content_script.js
```

I currently have webpack setup to transpile the background and content script with babel and copy the manifest as a standalone file but I can't figure out how to bundle the two index.html files (containing the contents of script.js and style.js) and keep the file structure of being in two separate folders. My current webpack config is:

```js
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const IS_PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: { background_script: './background_script.js', content_script: './content_script.js'},
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                    'extract-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: IS_PRODUCTION,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 8192,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new CopyWebpackPlugin({ patterns: [{ from: 'manifest.json', to: '.' }] }), new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
};
```

And my intent is the output into dist matches:

```
dist/
├── browserAction/
│   └── index.html
├── options/
│   └── index.html
├── manifest.json
├── background_script.js
└── content_script.js
```

What loaders do I need to use to achieve this? I've been experimenting with various ones but I can't get the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). An example configuration:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: {
    browser_action: './browserAction/script.js',
    options: './options/script.js',
    background_script: './background_script.js', 
    content_script: './content_script.js'
  },
  module: {
    // your loaders
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'browserAction/index.html',
      template: 'browserAction/index.html',
      chunks: ['browser_action']      
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'options/index.html',
      template: 'options/index.html',
      chunks: ['options']
    })
  ]
}
```

By the way, it looks like you're trying to write a browser extension; I'd recommend a boilerplate like [this](https://github.com/samuelsimoes/chrome-extension-webpack-boilerplate) which has webpack already configured.

Comment: I was playing around with it myself but I am getting the following error:
`1 ERROR in child compilations
webpack 5.2.0 compiled with 1 error in 1702 ms
error Command failed with exit code 1.`
There is no actual message so I have no idea what to make of it. And I saw that boilerplate but I wanted to try doing it from scratch to better understand webpack and that one also used deprecated loaders.

Comment: @Jim Hard to say what's going on without more detailed error messages. You could try adding `--stats verbose` to your webpack invocation (or add `stats: "verbose"` to your config) to hopefully narrow the issue more.